# regex "OR" matching in Django urlconf without sending match as a view parameter

Tags: regex, django, http-status-code-404, urlconf

In my Django urlconf, i'd like to return a 404 for requests probing for scripts.  Otherwise, the request is needlessly hitting the database to look for a corresponding FlatPage, since i'm using the FlatPage middleware.

My problem is that the following pattern, which matches correctly, is sending 'php', 'cgi', or 'pl' as the `template_name` argument to the `page_not_found` view function.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # don't even bother looking up a flatpage for these matches
    (r'\.(php|cgi|pl)$', 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'), 
    ...
)
```

What is a way to do that regex "or" logic without sending the match as a parameter to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-capturing groups are indicated with [`(?:...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-capturing group: `(?:regex)`

So your pattern would be:

`(r'\.(?:php|cgi|pl)$', 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'),`